# How to search and replace a text that has spaces before the text?

Tags: python, search, replace, spaces

I have a code that search if a line begin with a specified word and if it does, it changes that whole line with a specified input. However, it doesn't work for some lines if the line is indented by spaces? Is there a way to read the text directly and ignore the spaces.

Here is the code: (with comments on where the problem is)

```
import os

def template(filein):
    currdir = os.getcwd() # get current directory
    new_file = open(os.path.join(currdir,'maindir','template.in'),'wt')
    old_file = open(filein)
    for line in old_file:
        if line.startswith('   indent'):
            # this part works well because I put the exact number of spaces present in the text before the search word
            new_file.write('   indent == %s \n' % str('%(indent)s'))
        elif line.startswith('noindent'):
            # this part can't find noindent because i didn't specify the spaces before that that is present in the text
            new_file.write('noindent == %s \n' % str('%(noindent)s'))
        else:
            new_file.write(line)
    new_file.close()
    old_file.close()
```

Thanks

EDIT: I want to preserve all the spaces present in the original file, even in the lines that I modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) to remove the whitespace from the beginning (left) of a line:

```
for line in old_file:
    stripped_line = line.lstrip()
    # do your matching here against `stripped_line` instead of `line`
    # `line` still contains the original, non-stripped line
```

On a sidenote, I recommend using `with open('filename') as new_file`, instead of what you're doing now. This creates a block in which the file is available and makes sure the file is closed at the end of the block. See the end of [this section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in the docs.

Comment: I tried this but it removes all the spaces on the left for the lines that I do not want to change. I also want to preserve the original spaces after I have changed the line. Thanks

Comment: @mikeP: then, instead of replacing the line, you can store it in an other variable and check against that. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I tried the modification, however the indentation on the line that I changed still disappears. I want to preserve the original indentation even in the lines that I changed. Thanks.

Comment: @mikeP, in that case you might want to look at [Rik Poggi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961080/how-to-search-and-replace-a-text-that-has-spaces-before-the-text/8961423#8961423).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re

def replace(line, test_word, new_line):
    m = re.match(r'(\s*)(.*)', line)
    if m.group(2).startswith(test_word)
        return m.group(1) + new_line
```

Example:

```
>>> lines = ['    my indented line', 'my not indented line']
>>> for line in lines:
...     replace(line, 'my', 'new line')
'    new line'
'new line'
```

You can find in the official documentation [some examples](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) on how `group` works.

Comment: Thanks Rik. The file written still removes the original indention. I found a way around @Rob Wouters solution.

Comment: @mikeP: `m.group(1)` contains all your indentation so I can't see why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression matching instead of string matching:

```
if re.match('^\s*indent\b', line): 
    # line starts with 0 or more whitespace followed by "indent"
```